# Avoiding being locked out of Apple Store - password

Tags: password, apple-store

Twice I put in an incorrect password. I did not want to be locked out.. so I stopped trying.. I know that I can set a new one.. BUT I would prefer to keep the one that I have for the time being... If I wait a full day.. will I be allowed to try my password again (twice if nescessary)  or will I be locked out if I try it once more - even if 24 hours has passed?  Thanks

Comment: How do you know that you know the password, if it has already told you (twice) that you input an incorrect password? Wouldn't it be much faster to simply reset your password, and change it to your preferred password with an additional number (or something) at the end?

Answer (score 1):

On my MBA with Mavericks, I can find the Apple Store Password in my key chain.

Open key chain (in Utility folder), log in if you have to (usualy it is the same log in as your computer)

Next type "Apple Store" in the search window

Open it and use show password (you might have to provide log in again).

You should see the password.